# .NET Core IoC RegisterAssemblyTypes Equivalent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I am using the built in .NET Core IoC container. But I need functionality similar to that which comes with AutoFac. I want to limit the amount of third-party dependencies in this project. So I was hoping I could do something similar to the following AutoFac method in the  .NET Core IoC container:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyhere).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can do it with the built-in .NET Core IOC container, using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/scrutor) extension methods. It has got some nice assembly scanning functionalities.

Try this:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
                .FromAssemblies(typeof(yourassembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .AddClasses()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .WithScopedLifetime());
```

It applies on the built-in IOC container, though it's not itself a built-in package ([Scrutor package on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor/)):

Comment: My mistake, that's a set of extension methods provided by a package named Scrutor https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily implement your own method to register all assembly types for a given assembly or set of assemblies... the code would be along the lines of:

```
foreach (var implementationType in assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(type => !type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract))
{
    foreach(var interfaceType in implementationType.GetInterfaces())
    {
        services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, implementationType);
    }
}
```

The code selects all non-abstract types from `assemblies` and retrieves all interfaces for each type creating a `Singleton` registration for each interface/implementation pair.

---

I prefer to register all instances of an explicit interface (i.e., `ICommandHandler` or similar), so I add extension methods along the lines of `AddCommandHandlers` shown below for the few types I want *any* instance of to be registered...

```
public static void AddCommandHandlers(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    var serviceType = typeof(ICommandHandler);

    foreach (var implementationType in assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(type => serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract))
    {
        services.AddSingleton(serviceType, implementationType);
    }
}
```

Adding a call similar to `services.AddCommandHandlers(DomainAssembly.Reference);` in `ConfigureServices`...

I prefer this approach, because registering all interfaces for all types will add a lot of cruft registrations to your IoC container... typically not a huge deal, but cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer my assembly for type binding [Nuget Q101.ServiceCollectionExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Q101.ServiceCollectionExtensions)
maybe it will be convenient to use.

```
            services.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ITypeInterface).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("EndNameOfType") 
                    && t.GetInterfaces()
                        .Any(ti => ti.Name == typeof(ITypeInterface).Name))
            .AsScoped()    // Similarly Like As services.AddScoped(T1, T2)
            .PropertiesAutowired() // Set properties values                
            .Bind();        
...
        services.RegisterAssemblyTypesByName(typeof(IStudentRepository).Assembly,
            name => name.EndsWith("Repository")) // Condition for name of type
            .AsScoped()    // Similarly Like As services.AddScoped(T1, T2)
            // Set binding like as services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()                 
            .Bind();
```

there is a small instruction manual on the github repository
https://github.com/Axelweaver/q101-net-core22-service-collection-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can probably implement your own extension method to do that kind of thing, but you're also able to simply use Autofac if it has a feature you want. Is there some reason you can'd to that? To do so, you just configure it and return it from `ConfigureServices`, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container).

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    // Add other framework services

    // Add Autofac
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule<DefaultModule>();
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to build an application without any non MS dependencies. But if it's not possible I guess I'll have to go with Autofac.